# Extract 8 digit numbers between values in a column using excel functions

Tags: excel

I have column which has combination of the values i want, along with the dates

[image]

And I want specifically those 8 digit number in next column extracting them alone leaving the dates.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**-

[image]

Note- the set of values to be extracted is constantly 8 digits and doesn't necessarily have to start with 55.

Comment: Post data as text so that we can copy.

Comment: So if the number is always followed by the / then use mid() and find()

Comment: @Harun24hr, Can I use this formula in VBA code to auto execute it ?

Comment: For vba there is RegEx. VBA would be more easier.

Comment: @Harun24hr, could you please share it as well.. thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `FILTERXML()` like-

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"/","</s><s>"),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(., '.'))]"))
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747